# Uploading from Unity to Parse makes file corrupted

Tags: c#, file-upload, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, texture2d

I am trying to figure out how to upload an image from unity to Parse but with no luck? I think I am doing this the right way, but must be missing something on the way?

Here is how I do it:

```
void ConvertTexture2D(){
    byte[] data = userImage.EncodeToPNG();
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("user.png", data);
    Task saveTask = file.SaveAsync();

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Players");
    query.GetAsync(Constant.ParseID).ContinueWith(t =>
                                                  {
        PlayerData = t.Result;
        UpdateOldUser(file);

    });
}

void UpdateOldUser(ParseFile file){
    PlayerData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                                        {
        PlayerData["profileimg"] = file;
        PlayerData.SaveAsync();
    });
}
```

userImage is an Texture2D.

Here is the result: http://files.parse.com/c8f1e3e7-d8e6-4fba-84c3-168d0153350d/dc1001fb-db2d-43bc-934d-ca70c0b8198e-user.png

I am really hoping for quick help on this. I am stuck here :-/

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "makes file corrupted"? It's a correct PNG file. The only problem is that server returns wrong Content-Type in HTTP response. It is now "application/json", while it should be "image/png".

Answer (score 0):

The file is not corrupted. Everything worked just fine. It's just that the Parse data browser doesn't display images with the correct http header. You can verify the image by grabbing it with wget:

```
wget http://files.parse.com/c8f1e3e7-d8e6-4fba-84c3-168d0153350d/dc1001fb-db2d-43bc-934d-ca70c0b8198e-user.png
```

I can see that it's a photo looking out a window.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting PlayerData before calling PlayerData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith

```
void UpdateOldUser(ParseFile file){

PlayerData["profileImage"] =file;

            PlayerData.SaveAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {


                if (task.IsCanceled) {
                    // the save was cancelled.
                } else if (task.IsFaulted) {


                        // print parse exception
                        foreach(var e in task.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                            ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
                            Debug.Log("Error message " + parseException.Message);
                            Debug.Log("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
                        }

                } else {
                }
            });
       }
```